# Auto-close menu sections on open

Tags: mmenu

We would like to only have one menu section open at a time using mmenu and so does anyone know how we could automatically close any opened sections when a section is expanded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i managed to come up with this which works, there's probably a better way to do it:

```
$("#mm-0 a[href^=#]").click(function() {
    var clickedMenu = $(this);

    $("#mm-0 a[href^=#]").parent().each(function( i ) {
        $(this).removeClass("mm-opened");
    });

    if($(clickedMenu).parent().hasClass("mm-opened")){
        $(clickedMenu).parent().removeClass("mm-opened");
    }else{
        $(clickedMenu).parent().addClass("mm-opened");
    }
});
```

So i basically add an onclick handler to any anchor links in the menu and then update the class.